# How to find text fields that contains a list of words

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using `Oracle PLSQL`.

I want to return TextFields that contains a list of words (with 'and' operator between them).
The result string must contain all the words provided from the user, the order is not importent.

**Example:**

`param_col varchar2(100):= 'Project|Data|Book';`

(The list of words are unknown, depend on user parameter)

**TextField:**

```
1.'The Project will contain Data from Book'

2.'The Project Data is not valid.

3.'Project is the best data Book exists'
```

---

**Expected Result:**

```
1.'The Project will contain Data from Book'

3.'Project is the best data Book exists'
```

Comment: have you already tried something? we are not here to do homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option. See comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col) as
  3    -- Test sample data
  4    (select 1, 'The Project will contain Data from Book' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'The Project Data is not valid'           from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'Project is the best data Book exists'    from dual
  7    ),
  8  param (par) as
  9    -- input parameter
 10    (select 'Project|Data|Book' from dual),
 11  --
 12  spltest as
 13    -- split TEST sentences to words
 14    (select id,
 15            lower(regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value)) val
 16     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 17                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 18                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 19    ),
 20  splpar as
 21    -- split PARAMETER into words; include IDs from TEST
 22    (select t.id,
 23            lower(regexp_substr(p.par, '[^\|]+', 1, column_value)) val
 24     from param p cross join test t
 25                  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 26                                                 connect by level <= regexp_count(p.par, '\|') + 1
 27                                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 28    )
 29  -- final result: select rows from the TEST table ...
 30  select t.id, t.col
 31  from test t
 32  -- ... where ID is contained in intersected set of values from SPLTEST and SPLPAR ...
 33  where t.id in (select x.id from (select t1.id, t1.val from spltest t1
 34                                   intersect
 35                                   select p.id, p.val from splpar p
 36                                  ) x
 37                 group by x.id
 38                 -- ... while that "intersected set" has to contain all values from the PARAM
 39                 having count(*) = (select regexp_count(p1.par, '\|') + 1
 40                                    from param p1
 41                                   )
 42                );

        ID COL
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 The Project will contain Data from Book
         3 Project is the best data Book exists

SQL>
```